# What font do I need to use for arrows?

Tags: fonts, arrows, unicode

What Unicode fonts allow you to input unicode characters like for example arrows? And how do you make it work with another font like `tex-gyre-schola`
Example code:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Schola}
```

Edit: The Arrows I am in need of is `U+2B9A`

Comment: you can use the albatross program distributed with texlive to check which fonts support a particular character. You need to be more specific than "arrows" unicode has thousands of arrow characters from simple → which will be supported by many text font to exotic arrows of various sorts that are only supported by specialist symbol fonts

Answer (score 2):

All of them should contain most of the arrows, but XITS Math, Stix Two Math and New Computer Modern Math are especially comprehensive.

So, for example, if your main math font does not include ↜ (U+219C), AKA `\leftwavearrow`, you might import it from another font with a command like:

```
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[ range={\leftwavearrow, \rightwavearrow},
                             Scale = MatchLowercase ]
```

You can look up [a table of several math fonts here](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/newcomputermodern/doc/newcm-unimath-symbols.pdf) if you’re wondering about any specific character and what command to use for it.  Most of the arrows are listed under relation symbols.

As David Carlisle brought up in the comments, you can also use the `albatross` program to see which fonts contain a symbol.  You can look up every math symbol in the document above, [or this one, which might be more up-to-date,](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/unicodetex/latex/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf)  or [another chart of Unicode symbols.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols_by_subject) On page 44 of this document, we see that `\leftwavearrow` is U+0219C, so the command

```
albatross "0x219C"
```

will list all the fonts that have it.